# Equal powers in domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a domain. If $0\neq a,b\in R$ are such that $a^n=b^n$, for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then is it true that there exists $\zeta\in R^\ast$ such that $\zeta^n=1$ and $a=\zeta b$? If the answer is negative what are the conditions to put on $R$ in such a way that the claim is true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set $\zeta=\dfrac ab$. It belongs to he field of fractions of $R$, and satisfies $\zeta^n=1$.

It is integral over $R$, hence it belongs to $R$ if $R$ is integrally closed.

Comment: As a counterexample in the case where $R$ is not integrally closed, consider $R = \mathbb{Z}[2i]$ (the element $i = (2i)/2$ satisfies $X^2 + 1 = 0$ but is not in $R$). Then pick $a = 2, b = 2i, n = 4$. We have $2^4 = 16 = (2i)^4$ but $i \not\in R$.